How to fix the directory name format from 'key=value' to 'value' generated by PySpark 'partition_by' function?
I'm trying to customize directory names generated by PySpark using partition_by on these two columns (date and customer),
Dataframe is similar to this:
+----------+--------+
|date      |customer|
+----------+--------+
|2024-02-11|Robert  | 
|2023-12-01|Linda   |
+----------+--------+

At the moment, the resultant path for the file created by 'partition_by' is this:
somebucket/date=2024-02-11/customer=Robert/file.parquet
somebucket/date=2023-12-01/customer=Linda/file.parquet
But I need to include a last part of this path. In this case, a sub-directory called 'batch'. So, the result must be:
somebucket/date=2024-02-11/customer=Robert/batch/file.parquet
somebucket/date=2023-12-01/customer=Linda/batch/file.parquet
My failure solution was to add a new 'batch' column (using the 'withColumn' function) with a useless value.
+----------+--------+-------+
|date      |customer| batch |
+----------+--------+-------+
|2024-02-11|Robert  | 0     |
|2023-12-01|Linda   | 0     |
+----------+--------+-------+

But the result was this:
somebucket/date=2024-02-11/customer=Robert/batch=0/file.parquet
somebucket/date=2023-12-01/customer=Linda/batch=0/file.parquet
As you can see, this is not what I need.
Is there a way to fix that using PySpark or with something that will not make me have huge performance problems?

what if you moved all of the files inside Robert/ to a new directory called Robert/batch/ using the os library?

I can't do that. I need exactly what I asked. But thanks anyway!
